# Draw Spiral coil using DXFwriter API in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dxf

> Hi people,
> I am trying to generate the PCB coil dxf format using
> python DXFwriter

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dxfwrite/

> There are built in shapes like  ARC,Circle,Polyline,Polymesh.
>
> I am not able to draw spiral shape using the API.
>
> Can any one please guide me with this query.

Answer (score 1):

> Hi People ,
> I am able to create the Spiral shapes using the library as below
>
> I am using the shape Polyline api

```
for t in range(0,360):
angle=t*.1
y=(b+angle)*math.sin(angle)
x=(a+angle)*math.cos(angle)
polyline.add_vertex((x,y))
```

Where the a & b are the constants
Using the equation

```
r=a+b@
```